# Conditional data.table merge with .EACHI

Tags: r, data.table

I have been playing around with the newer `data.table` conditional merge feature and it is very cool. I have a situation where I have two tables, `dtBig` and `dtSmall`, and there are multiple row matches in both datasets when this conditional merge takes place. Is there a way to aggregate these matches using a function like `max` or `min` for these multiple matches? Here is a reproducible example that tries to mimic what I am trying to accomplish.

### Set up environment

```
## docker run --rm -ti rocker/r-base
## install.packages("data.table", type = "source",repos = "http://Rdatatable.github.io/data.table")
```

### Create two fake datasets

A create a "big" table with 50 rows (10 values for each ID).

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1L)

# Simulate some data
dtBig <- data.table(ID=c(sapply(LETTERS[1:5], rep, 10, simplify = TRUE)), ValueBig=ceiling(runif(50, min=0, max=1000)))
dtBig[, Rank := frank(ValueBig, ties.method = "first"), keyby=.(ID)]

    ID ValueBig Rank
 1:  A      266    3
 2:  A      373    4
 3:  A      573    5
 4:  A      909    9
 5:  A      202    2
---                 
46:  E      790    9
47:  E       24    1
48:  E      478    2
49:  E      733    7
50:  E      693    6
```

Create a "small" dataset similar to the first, but with 10 rows (2 values for each ID)

```
dtSmall <- data.table(ID=c(sapply(LETTERS[1:5], rep, 2, simplify = TRUE)), ValueSmall=ceiling(runif(10, min=0, max=1000)))

    ID ValueSmall
 1:  A        478
 2:  A        862
 3:  B        439
 4:  B        245
 5:  C         71
 6:  C        100
 7:  D        317
 8:  D        519
 9:  E        663
10:  E        407
```

### Merge

I next want to perform a merge by `ID` and needs to merge only where `ValueSmall` is greater than or equal to `ValueBig`. For the matches, I want to grab the `max` ranked value in `dtBig`. I tried doing this two different ways. Method 2 gives me the desired output, but I am unclear why the output is different at all. It seems like it is just returning the last matched value.

```
## Method 1
dtSmall[dtBig, RankSmall := max(i.Rank), by=.EACHI, on=.(ID, ValueSmall >= ValueBig)]

## Method 2
setorder(dtBig, ValueBig)
dtSmall[dtBig, RankSmall2 := max(i.Rank), by=.EACHI, on=.(ID, ValueSmall >= ValueBig)]
```

### Results

```
    ID ValueSmall RankSmall RankSmall2 DesiredRank
 1:  A        478         1          4           4
 2:  A        862         1          7           7
 3:  B        439         3          4           4
 4:  B        245         1          2           2
 5:  C         71         1          1           1
 6:  C        100         1          1           1
 7:  D        317         1          2           2
 8:  D        519         3          5           5
 9:  E        663         2          5           5
10:  E        407         1          1           1
```

Is there a better `data.table` way of grabbing the max value in another `data.table` with multiple matches?

Comment: update - looks like there is an issue on the `data.table` github related to this question. (github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/733)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I next want to perform a merge by ID and needs to merge only where ValueSmall is greater than or equal to ValueBig. For the matches, I want to grab the max ranked value in dtBig.

```
setorder(dtBig, ID, ValueBig, Rank)
dtSmall[, r :=
  dtBig[.SD, on=.(ID, ValueBig <= ValueSmall), mult="last", x.Rank ]
]

    ID ValueSmall r
 1:  A        478 4
 2:  A        862 7
 3:  B        439 4
 4:  B        245 2
 5:  C         71 1
 6:  C        100 1
 7:  D        317 2
 8:  D        519 5
 9:  E        663 5
10:  E        407 1
```

I imagine it is considerably faster to sort dtBig and take the last matching row rather than to compute the max by .EACHI, but am not entirely sure. If you don't like sorting, just save the previous sort order so it can be reverted to afterwards.

---

> Is there a way to aggregate these matches using a function like max or min for these multiple matches?

For this more general problem, .EACHI works, just making sure you're doing it for each row of the target table (dtSmall in this case), so...

```
dtSmall[, r :=
  dtBig[.SD, on=.(ID, ValueBig <= ValueSmall), max(x.Rank), by=.EACHI ]$V1
]
```

Comment: Since there's no data.table vignette on joins yet, folks could check out my notes to get better intuition for the syntax: http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/tables.html#dt-joins (section "updating in a join").

Comment: Thanks @Frank - I didn't realize there was already an issue open on this (https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/733). Very complete documentation!

Comment: @Mike.Gahan Good find. I knew that issue, but never thought of it as a resolution to this problem before.